# Curious limit with variable under integral?

Tags: calculus, limits, definite-integrals, improper-integrals

$$\lim_{p\to0} \left[{p \int_{-\infty}^\infty {{{\ln}^2(1+x)}\over{ (p^2 +x^2)}^2}}\,\mathrm dx\right]$$
Tried to calculate without finding the value of the integral, but by putting  the small parameter inside.And making a clever substitution. I could not do this.
Please write as many different solutions as possible. With or without finding the integral itself . Advanced methods like complex analysis are welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint. Show that
$$\lim_{p\to0} \left[{p \int_{-\infty}^\infty {{{\ln}^2(1+x)-x^2}\over{ (p^2 +x^2)}^2}}\,\mathrm dx\right]=0$$
then note that for $p>0$
$${p \int_{-\infty}^\infty {{x^2}\over{ (p^2 +x^2)}^2}}\,\mathrm dx=\frac{\pi}{2}.$$

Answer (score 1):

Given $f(x)=\dfrac{\log^2(1+x)} {(p^2 +x^2)^2}$
$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x)\,\mathrm dx=2\pi i\,\text{Res}(f,p \,i)$$
$p\,i$ is a double pole so we have

$$\mathrm {Res} (f,p\,i)=\lim _{x\to pi}{\frac {d}{dx}}\left[(x-pi)^{2}\dfrac{\log^2(1+x)} {(x-pi)^2(x+pi)^2}\right]=\lim _{x\to pi}{\frac {d}{dx}}\left[\dfrac{\log^2(1+x)} {(x+pi)^2}\right]=$$
$$=\lim _{x\to pi}\frac{-2 \log (x+1) (-i p-x+(x+1) \log (x+1))}{(x+1) (x+i p)^3}=\frac{-i \log (1+i p) (-2 p+(p-i) \log (1+i p))}{4 p^3 (p-i)}$$
Thus we have 
$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x)\,\mathrm dx=2\pi i \,\frac{-i \log (1+i p) (-2 p+(p-i) \log (1+i p))}{4 p^3 (p-i)}=\frac{\pi  \log (1+i p) ((1+i p) \log (1+i p)-2 i p)}{2 (1+i p) p^3}$$

Finally
$$\lim_{p\to 0} \left[p \int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x)\,\mathrm dx\right]= \lim_{p\to 0} p \,\frac{\pi  \log (1+i p) ((1+i p) \log (1+i p)-2 i p)}{2 (1+i p) p^3}=$$
$$=\lim_{p\to 0}  \,\frac{\pi  \log (1+i p) ((1+i p) \log (1+i p)-2 i p)}{2 (1+i p) p^2}=\lim_{p\to 0}  \,\frac{\pi  \log (1+i p) \left(\log (1+i p)-\frac{2 p}{p-i}\right)}{2 p^2}=$$
$$=\lim_{p\to 0}  \,-\frac{\pi }{2} \frac{\log (1+i p)}{i p}\left( \frac{\log (1+i p)}{i p}-\frac{2}{i (p-i)}\right) =\frac{\pi}{2}$$

Hope this is useful